# How to convert wiki markup into text? R/wikipedir

Tags: r, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to run this code:

```
library(WikipediR)

wp_content <- page_content("en","wikipedia", page_name = "Aaron Halfaker", as_wikitext = T, clean_response = T)

wp_content <- wp_content$wikitext$`*`

print(wp_content)
```

But the output is in wiki markup:

```
[1] "{{Infobox scientist\n| name        = Aaron Halfaker\n| native_name = \n| native_name_lang = \n| image       = File:Halfaker,_Aaron_Sept_2013.jpg\n| image_size  = \n| alt         = \n| caption     = \n| birth_date  = {{birth date and age|1983|12|27}}\n| birth_place = [[Virginia, Minnesota]]<ref>{{Cite web |url=https://twitter.com/halfak/status/826529576906059780 |title=Twitter status |last=Halfaker |first=Aaron |website=Twitter |date=31 January 2017}}</ref>\n| death_date  = \n| death_place = \n| resting_place = \n| resting_place_coordinates =  <!--{{coord|LAT|LONG|type:landmark|display=inline,title}}-->\n| other_names = \n| residence   = \n| citizenship = \n| nationality = \n| fields      = [[Human-Computer Interaction]] <br/> [[computer-supported cooperative work]]\n| workplaces  = [[Wikimedia Foundation]]\n| patrons     = \n| alma_mater  = [[The College of St. Scholastica]] (B.S., 2006)<br/> [[University of Minnesota]] (Ph.D., 2013)<ref name=\"tmn\">{{cite web|url=http://tech.mn/news/2013/12/11/aaron-halfaker-wikimedia-foundation/|title=Wicked Smart: 5 questions with U of M PhD and Wikipedian Aaron Halfaker|date=11 December 2013|publisher=TechMN|accessdate=5 January 2015}}</ref><ref>{{Cite web |url=https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~halfak/docs/curriculum_vitae |title=Aaron Halfaker Curriculum Vitae}}</ref>\n..."
```

How can I convert that into plain text, or get it immediately as plain text.
I also tried to pass `as_wiktext = F`, but it didn't work.

Language - R.
Package - Wikipedir v1.5.0

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! can you please add an example of your desired output to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`as_wikitext = T` downloads the text with the wiki markup. By default, `page_content` downlads the page with HTML markup. Fortunately, there are numerous HTML parser available, one of the best ones being `rvest`. The following code downloads the page as HTML, parses it into an HTML structure using `rvest::read_html` and then parses that into plain text using `rvest::html_text`

```r
library(WikipediR)
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2

wp_content <- page_content(language = 'en', project = 'wikipedia', 'page_name' = 'Aaron Halfaker', as_wikitext = F)

html_text(read_html(wp_content$parse$text$`*`))
#> [1] "Aaron HalfakerBorn (1983-12-27) December 27, 1983 (age 36)Virginia, Minnesota[1]Alma materThe College of St. Scholastica (B.S., 2006)University of Minnesota (Ph.D., 2013)..."
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: You can upvote the answer if you found it helpful :)